# How does this lighting calculation work?

Tags: c++, qt, graphics, 3d, lighting

I have that piece of code that is responsible for lighting a pyramid.

```
float Geometric3D::calculateLight(int vert1, int vert2, int vert3) {

    float ax = tabX[vert2] - tabX[vert1];
    float ay = tabY[vert2] - tabY[vert1];
    float az = tabZ[vert2] - tabZ[vert1];

    float bx = tabX[vert3] - tabX[vert1];
    float by = tabY[vert3] - tabY[vert1];
    float bz = tabZ[vert3] - tabZ[vert1];

    float Nx = (ay * bz) - (az * by);
    float Ny = (az * bx) - (ax * bz);;
    float Nz = (ax * by) - (ay * bx);;

    float Lx = -300.0f;
    float Ly = -300.0f;
    float Lz = -1000.0f;

    float lenN = sqrtf((Nx * Nx) + (Ny * Ny) + (Nz * Nz));
    float lenL = sqrtf((Lx * Lx) + (Ly * Ly) + (Lz * Lz));

    float res = ((Nx * Lx) + (Ny * Ly) + (Nz * Lz)) / (lenN * lenL);
    if (res < 0.0f)
        res = -res;
    return res;
}
```

I cannot understand calculations at the end. Can someone explain me the maths that is behind them? I know that firstly program calculates two vectors of a plane to compute the normal of it (which goes for vector N). Vector L stand for lighting but what happens next? Why do we calculate length of normal and light then multiply it and divide by their sizes?

Comment: The last part does `res = (N dot L) / (|N| * |L|)`, which effectively computes a `cos` for an angle between `N` and `L`.

Comment: And diffuse reflection is often modeled as with some power of the cosine of the angle between the surface normal and the direction of the incident light.

Comment: To find some illustrative doc. I googled "opengl lighting calculation". (Including "opengl" was the trick to prevent high-ranked hits with ads. for all sorts of lamp shops...) This is a nice doc.: [Modern OpenGL 07 – More Lighting: Ambient, Specular, Attenuation, Gamma](https://www.tomdalling.com/blog/modern-opengl/07-more-lighting-ambient-specular-attenuation-gamma/) which mentions the mathematical background as well but there were a lot of others also.

Comment: The `if (res < 0.0f) res = -res;` is bothering me a bit. If I didn't get it wrong it should be: `if (res < 0.0f) res = 0.0f;` You can imagine it as follows: If angle between normal N and light ray L is 0: full light (`res` = 1). If angle is between 0 and 90: dimmed light (according to cos() which "goes" towards 0 with increasing angle). But if angle is > 90 the face is turned away from light. Hence there should be _no_ lighting (`res` = 0), of course, no "negative" lighting, but definitely no _positive_ lighting (which would result from `if (res < 0) res = -res;`).